# IEEE754単精度浮動小数のバイアスについて

Tags: javascript

IEEE754単精度浮動小数のバイアスについてです。
指数表現が-126から127となる理由などはあるのでしょうか。-127〜126としなかったのには理由があるものだと思っていますが分かりません。ご教授ください。

> 符号ビットは表現する数値の符号（正負）を示す。指数部は 8 ビットで、符号なし整数として見た場合は 0 から 255 の値をとり、0 の時はゼロか非正規化数であることを、1 から 254 の時は -127 のゲタ履き（バイアス付き）表現で -126 から 127 の指数を、255 の時は無限大または NaN であることを示す。
> [Wikipedia](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8D%98%E7%B2%BE%E5%BA%A6%E6%B5%AE%E5%8B%95%E5%B0%8F%E6%95%B0%E7%82%B9%E6%95%B0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[WikiPedia の IEEE754 解説](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) の 32ビット単精度の交換形式 の箇所によると

指数部も２の補数にすると仮数部と指数部の両方に符号が入り込むので大小比較が複雑になるから、指数部は表現上「正数」としておく旨の記述があります。

よく使われる＝計算回路の設計上での注意点がよく知られている＝回路にバグが入りにくい、ということなので標準的なエクセスN形式 (8bit) を採用すると、オフセット数値はほぼ自動で 127 ということになります（ほかの数値を選ぶのは非標準＝回路設計上避けられたはずのバグを招く可能性あり＝採用しづらい）。バイナリ記述上 0 および 255 には別な意味をもたせたので、そうすると指数の有効な値としては自動的に -126 から 127 にならざるを得ないということでしょう。

---

エクセスN形式 [WikiPedia の解説](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AC%A6%E5%8F%B7%E4%BB%98%E6%95%B0%E5%80%A4%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE)とは

- 意味論的数値と表記上の数値を、ある数値 N だけ（バイアスとか下駄ばき分とか言う）ずらす
- `n` ビット値に対して `2**(n-1) -1` の差を使うことが多い
- この例では 8bit 値だから `2**7-1=127` の差をつける
- 表記上の値を正数にしたいのだから

  - 意味論→表記の際にはプラスする
  - 表記→意味論の際にはマイナスする

なので IEEE754 の指数部においては

- 表記上の値 `1` は意味 `1-127 = -126` になる
- 表記上の値 `254` は意味 `254-127 = +127` になる
- 表記上の値 `0` と `255` (全ビットが 0 または 1 な値）は特別扱いする、つまり指数とみなさない

ということで [-126, +127] の範囲になるわけです（ハードウエア上の演算回路の設計・実装でバグを出さないための知恵といえるでしょう）

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。私の理解力が不足していることに尽きると思うのですが、> ”オフセット数値は 127 ということになります。バイナリ記述上 0 および 255 には別な意味をもたせたので、そうすると指数の有効な値としては自動的に -126 から 127 にならざるを得ないということでしょう。" の部分が理解できていません。よろしければもう少し教えていただけないでしょうか

Comment: ありがとうございます。とても分かりやすく解説いただき、疑問が解けました。以前の私の質問にも回答いただいていたようで重ねてお礼申し上げます。